# How can I resize, rotate part of the path in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, resize, tools

As a Photoshop user I don't know exactly how to rotate or resize only the part of the selected path in Illustrator. When I do this in Photoshop I simply select part of the path by using direct selection tool (with key A). Then I press Ctrl+T (or Cmd+T in Mac) and make a rotation only for selected points. This step by step guide does not work in Illustrator. Every time I select points and try to rotate them, all path rotates together with those points. But I want to rotate only selected points. How can I achieve this task in Adobe Illustrator. It sounds very stupid question, but by using keywords "rotate part, section of the path" in google it's impossible to find right answers, because those keywords has double meanings. Thank you for your help.

[image: How I rotate part of the path in Photoshop]

Comment: Same thing as with photoshop, just replace `Cmd+T` with `E` - Which is the `Free Transform tool`, that can be found in the toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works nearly the same. Select the points you want to rotate as you would in photoshop with the white **direct selection tool** (hit <kbd>A</kbd>). Then select the **Rotate Tool** (hit <kbd>R</kbd>). Grab a point and rotate.

**Tips**:

- If you click once you will move the rotate pivot there.
- If you alt click it moves the pivot there and opens up a dialog for typing exact values.

[image: rotate]

**Screen capture 1**: Several ways to rotate.

Comment: I need to agree that Joonas suggestion is closer to my needs, but I accepted your answer, because you wrote it as answer but not as a comment. Thanks ;)

Comment: @edukulele its nearly the same answer, its just written as self contained an has some tips.

Comment: so how can I vote up Joonas answer then?

Comment: You need more points, voting on comments does not really do anything beneficial for @Joonas tough